# Changing images with right or left arrow key

Tags: javascript

I've built this gallery
https://jsfiddle.net/ramamamagagaulala/do4yLxcz/

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.work-item');
let best = document.querySelector('.work-modal');
let main = document.querySelector('.work-modal__item');

console.log(images)

let closeButton = document.getElementById("closee");

images.forEach(function(ref) {

ref.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let newImage = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;


  best.classList.add('work-modal--show');
  main.style.backgroundImage = `url( ${newImage} )`;
})


})

closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  best.classList.remove('work-modal--show');
});
```

basically, it works like this:

- you click an item.
- JavaScript checks what IMG this item contains.
- a modal window opens up.
- then the IMG that is associated with the item, is going to be displayed as the background image of this modal.

So far so good, however, I would like to build a function so I can press the arrow keys on my keyboard and the next image is going to be displayed.

What I've tried is to select the IMG of the nextSibling while clicking. Then I have used this variable to set up the background image of the modal window. But this only worked once.

Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: use the 'keyup' event listener on the document and check the `event.keyCode` property for your left key.

Comment: I did that but that only works once. When I press the key again, the image does not change.

Comment: It is not very clear in your title. Do you want to react on keyboard event (left, right) or click? In the content of the question, you cite again "while clicking", so be more explicit, please

Comment: yeah, you're right. Sorry about that. I want to react on a keyboard event.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest have list of images urls in an array in .js file, and then you show one modal, click right/left and just change img src value to next/previous array element, untill get to either end of array.

Comment: but then how to make the image that has been clicked also the background image?

Comment: Just save it in variable currentImage and update it when you click on image.

Comment: In React save in component/redux state

Answer (score 0):

There are three things we need to do for this problem

- Storing the image source in an array
- Keep track of the position of the image index
- Add an event listener to track the keypress for next & prev button on your keyboard

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.work-item');
let best = document.querySelector('.work-modal');
let main = document.querySelector('.work-modal__item');


let closeButton = document.getElementById("closee");
let currentIndex = -1;
let imgSrc = [];

images.forEach(function(ref,index) {
  imgSrc.push(ref.children[0].getAttribute("src"));
    ref.addEventListener('click', function(){
      let newImage = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
      best.classList.add('work-modal--show');
      main.style.backgroundImage = `url( ${newImage} )`;
      currentIndex = index
   });

})


closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  best.classList.remove('work-modal--show');
});

let doc = document.getElementById("work");

window.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if(event.keyCode === 39){
   // next event
    if(currentIndex < imgSrc.length -1 ){
     main.style.backgroundImage = `url( ${imgSrc[currentIndex+1]} )`;
     currentIndex=currentIndex+1;
    } else {
     alert("Reached last image")
    }
  } else if(event.keyCode === 37){
   // prev event
    if(currentIndex > 0){
      main.style.backgroundImage = `url( ${imgSrc[currentIndex-1]} )`;
      currentIndex=currentIndex-1;
    } else {
     alert("Reached first image")
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.work-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
  }


img {
  width: 250px;
}

.work-item__img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  opacity: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}




  /* modal */

.work-modal{
  display: none;
}

.work-modal--show{
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.work-modal__item{
  height: 70vh;
  width: 80vw;
  border:0.5rem solid var(--yellow);
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
  .work-modal__item{
    height: 80vh;
    width: 60vw;
  }
}
.work-modal__close{
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: var(--brightYellow);
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  transition: color 0.5s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.work-modal__close:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="work section-padding" id="work">
  <div class="work-container">
 
        <div class="work-item item-1">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2683138/pexels-photo-2683138.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="" class="work-item__img">
    </div>
    
     <div class="work-item item-2">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2736220/pexels-photo-2736220.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="" class="work-item__img">
    </div>
    
    
     <div class="work-item item-3">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2928178/pexels-photo-2928178.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="" class="work-item__img">
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
</section>





<div class="work-modal">
  <div class="work-modal__item"></div>
  <div class="work-modal__close">
    <i id="closee" class="fas fa-window-close">close</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/aamin89/b5wp3kez/1/